# Problem with an activity-dependent dependency: getting Dagger/MissingBinding

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I get MissingBinding with the following code:

```
class AnActivityComponent @Inject constructor(activity: Activity)

@Module
abstract class MainActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeAndroidInjector(): MainActivity

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindActivity(mainActivity: MainActivity): Activity
}

@Module
abstract class AppModule(app: App) {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindApplication(app: App): Application
}

@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, AndroidInjectionModule::class, MainActivityModule::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {
}
```

However, if I change

```
class AnActivityComponent @Inject constructor(activity: Activity)
```

to

```
class AnActivityComponent @Inject constructor(activity: MainActivity)
```

it works fine. I'm binding Activity in the activity module, what's the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turned out that the `@ContributesAndroidInjector` doesn't include the module it's declared in into the lookup, so you have to organise your code better:

```
class AnActivityComponent @Inject constructor(activity: Activity)

@Module
abstract class ActivitiesModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainActivityModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeAndroidInjector(): MainActivity
}

@Module
abstract class MainActivityModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindActivity(mainActivity: MainActivity): Activity
}

@Module
abstract class AppModule(app: App) {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindApplication(app: App): Application
}

@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, AndroidInjectionModule::class, ActivitiesModule::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {
}
```